# Ignoring parameters in routes

Tags: scala, routes, playframework-2.1

One of the nice things about Play is that it doesn't dictate your URL format. That's great because I'm porting an application and need to retain backwards compatibility with old URLs.

I want to match all URLs that start with `/foo/bar`:

```
/foo/bar
/foo/bar/0
/foo/bar/1
/foo/bar/baz
```

How do I do this?

I can't find much documentation. I found old docs for [1.2.7](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/routes) that said

> You can tell Play that you want to match both URLs by adding a question mark after the trailing slash. For example:
>
> `GET     /clients/?       Clients.index`
>
> The URI pattern cannot have any optional part except for that trailing slash.

That's a little funny to be its own special case. IDK how much is still true, since it isn't in the current documentation.

---

I tried

```
GET     /foo/bar             Foo.bar
GET     /foo/bar/*unused     Foo.bar
```

and

```
GET     /foo/bar             Foo.bar
GET     /foo/bar/$unused<.*> Foo.bar
```

but compilation failed.

> Compilation error[Missing parameter in call definition: unused]

---

Finally, I tried redefining `Foo.bar` to take a junk argument (with default as the empty string).

```
GET     /foo/bar             Foo.bar
GET     /foo/bar/*unused     Foo.bar(unused)
```

and

```
GET     /foo/bar             Foo.bar
GET     /foo/bar/$unused<.*> Foo.bar(unused)
```

but it still didn't work.

> conflicting symbols both originated in file '/home/paul/my-play-project/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/routes_reverseRouting.scala'

---

How do I match URL prefixes, or ignore parameters?

Comment: I think you are on the right track, but need to define two separate methods to replace `Foo.bar`, one that takes the unused parameter, and the other that doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is thanks to @wingedsubmariner

```
GET     /foo/bar             Foo.bar
GET     /foo/bar/$unused<.*> Foo.barIgnoreUnused(unused)
```

with

```
object Foo {

  def bar = Ok("")

  def barIgnoreUnused(unused: String) = bar

}
```

---

Surprisingly, this doesn't seem to work.

```
GET     /foo/bar$unused<.*> Foo.bar(unused)
```

---

Probably the correct thing for Play to do is allow unused parameters, but this (admittedly ugly) solution works.